# BiodiversityR::rankabundance() function doesn't calculate plower and pupper values

Tags: r

I believe my data.frame is organized the same as [[the example](https://rdrr.io/cran/BiodiversityR/man/rankabundance.html)][1](https://rdrr.io/cran/BiodiversityR/man/rankabundance.html) but I do not get `plower` and `pupper` values. My code was `rankabundance(data,y="env")`. Please let me know what might cause the issue. Here is part of the data.

I notice that `dput(head(data)` show my row.names as `row.names = c(NA, 6L)`, which is different from how the `dune` data row was formated -- `row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")` but if I check `row.names(head(data)` I got `[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"`, which is the same as if I applied `row.names(head(dune))` so I am confused.

Species data

```
structure(list(DIGSA = c(2.96512, 0, 3.7184, 0, 0, 9.82196), 
    SETFA = c(6.67152, 166.60268, 0, 0, 1876.55032, 0), SETLU = c(0, 
    0, 69.3056, 103.0848, 0, 0), PANCA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ECHCG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 114.8984, 0), ERBVI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 16.30816), CYPES = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AMATA = c(27.24204, 
    0, 5.264, 1.232, 496.10164, 2582.80484), CHEAL = c(0, 44.84744, 
    35.4816, 29.2096, 459.96424, 0), SOLPT = c(0, 4.81832, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), PHYSU = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POLCC = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), POLPY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ABUTH = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1742.9346, 0), TAROF = c(0, 0, 0, 1.6352, 0, 0), EPHHT = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CIRAR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SONAR = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MORAL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OXAST = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POLLA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASCSY = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POLAV = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLAMA = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PANVI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PANDI = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CONAR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), IPOHE = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RUMCR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EPHMA = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 14.8256, 0), RYE__ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SOLNI = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ACRSP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BROIN = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POAPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POATR = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTPI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BROTE = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Environment data

```
structure(list(Plot = c(11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), Side = c("W", 
"E", "W", "E", "W", "E"), Crop = c("corn", "corn", "oat", "oat", 
"soybean", "soybean"), Trt = c("C3", "C3", "O4", "O4", "S2", 
"S2"), Rot = c("3-year", "3-year", "4-year", "4-year", "2-year", 
"2-year"), Herb = c("conv", "low", "conv", "low", "conv", "conv"
), Block = c("rep1", "rep1", "rep1", "rep1", "rep1", "rep1"), 
    Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My result

```
rankabundance(data,env)
      rank abundance proportion plower pupper accumfreq logabun rankfreq
CHEAL    1  144547.2       42.6    NaN    NaN      42.6     5.2      2.6
AMATA    2   83784.9       24.7    NaN    NaN      67.2     4.9      5.3
SETFA    3   47263.4       13.9    NaN    NaN      81.2     4.7      7.9
TAROF    4   17524.0        5.2    NaN    NaN      86.3     4.2     10.5
ABUTH    5   17472.1        5.1    NaN    NaN      91.5     4.2     13.2
SETLU    6   13955.4        4.1    NaN    NaN      95.6     4.1     15.8
```

Example result

```
rankabundance(dune,dune.env)
         rank abundance proportion plower pupper accumfreq logabun rankfreq
Poatriv     1        63        9.2    6.0   12.4       9.2     1.8      3.3
Lolipere    2        58        8.5    4.9   12.0      17.7     1.8      6.7
Scorautu    3        54        7.9    5.7   10.0      25.5     1.7     10.0
Bracruta    4        49        7.2    4.6    9.7      32.7     1.7     13.3
Agrostol    5        48        7.0    3.3   10.7      39.7     1.7     16.7
Poaprat     6        48        7.0    4.8    9.2      46.7     1.7     20.0
Trifrepe    7        47        6.9    4.5    9.2      53.6     1.7     23.3
Alopgeni    8        36        5.3    1.8    8.7      58.8     1.6     26.7
Elymrepe    9        26        3.8    1.1    6.5      62.6     1.4     30.0
Planlanc   10        26        3.8    1.2    6.4      66.4     1.4     33.3
Eleopalu   11        25        3.6    0.3    7.0      70.1     1.4     36.7
Anthodor   12        21        3.1    0.8    5.4      73.1     1.3     40.0
Sagiproc   13        20        2.9    0.9    5.0      76.1     1.3     43.3
Juncarti   14        18        2.6    0.4    4.9      78.7     1.3     46.7
Rumeacet   15        18        2.6    0.3    4.9      81.3     1.3     50.0
Achimill   16        16        2.3    0.7    4.0      83.6     1.2     53.3
Bromhord   17        15        2.2    0.4    4.0      85.8     1.2     56.7
Ranuflam   18        14        2.0    0.4    3.7      87.9     1.1     60.0
Bellpere   19        13        1.9    0.6    3.2      89.8     1.1     63.3
Juncbufo   20        13        1.9    0.0    3.8      91.7     1.1     66.7
Salirepe   21        11        1.6   -0.3    3.6      93.3     1.0     70.0
Callcusp   22        10        1.5   -0.3    3.2      94.7     1.0     73.3
Hyporadi   23         9        1.3   -0.4    3.1      96.1     1.0     76.7
Trifprat   24         9        1.3   -0.3    2.9      97.4     1.0     80.0
Airaprae   25         5        0.7   -0.4    1.8      98.1     0.7     83.3
Comapalu   26         4        0.6   -0.3    1.5      98.7     0.6     86.7
Vicilath   27         4        0.6   -0.1    1.3      99.3     0.6     90.0
Empenigr   28         2        0.3   -0.3    0.9      99.6     0.3     93.3
Cirsarve   29         2        0.3   -0.3    0.9      99.9     0.3     96.7
Chenalbu   30         1        0.1   -0.2    0.5     100.0     0.0    100.0
```

Thank you.

Comment: When I use `rankabundance(data, env)` I get some values. Everything after row 11 becomes 0 in `abundance`, `proportion`, `plower` and `pupper` columns.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I cleared my `cache` and `history` but the problem persists. Do you know what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I had some all-zeros rows in the other part of the dataset. Removing those solved the problem.